# How do I refer to thousands of possible selectors in Stylus?

Tags: css, styles, stylus

I'm trying to write a Stylus script for a forum in which users may define custom text colour, font, or size. Specifically, I want to functionally negate those customs in favour of a universally defined default. The issue is, applying the requisite style to `post-text-content` only applies if that content is *already* in the default state. Each customisation to the text by a user creates its own unique `<span style>`, such that I would need to write thousands of lines in the style, each replacing `<span style="color:green">`,  and so on until I've exhausted every possible CSS colourname and hexcode; then I would have to repeat the same for text sizes (only five, thankfully) and fonts (I think the forum supports 22).

Effectively, I want a **single selector** for every possible `<span style="color:*">`. I can manually do the fonts and sizes if I have to. I tried the wildcard, it didn't work. Is there a wildcard I can use? Is there a specific method of negating any code within a certain div, when simply selecting that div fails to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but you can use [standard CSS property selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp):
`span[style~="color:"] { color: red !important; }`

/edit
Just realized you're better off with the tilde selector than the wildcard to not accidentially target something like `background-color:`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, don't know why I couldn't find it via search. I was putting the wildcard in the wrong place. Thank you!